# AssertJ: FlatMap list of lists after calling extracting

Tags: java, java-8, assertj

So I have a Map of String/String list pairs, and what I want to do is after extraction, combine the returned lists into one list on which i can perform more assertions:

**MyTest.java**

```
Map<String, List<String>> testMap  = new HashMap<>();
List<String> nameList = newArrayList("Dave", "Jeff");
List<String> jobList = newArrayList("Plumber", "Builder");
List<String> cityList = newArrayList("Dover", "Boston");

testMap.put("name", nameList);
testMap.put("job", jobList);
testMap.put("city", cityList);

assertThat(testMap).hasSize(3)
    .extracting("name", "city")
    //not sure where to go from here to flatten list of lists
    // I want to do something like .flatMap().contains(expectedValuesList)
```

When I call extracting, it pulls out the list values into a list of lists, which is fine, but I cant call flatExtracting after that as there are no property names to pass in, and from what I've read it doesn't seem like a custom extractor would be appropriate(or else I'm not entirely sure how to put it together). Is there another way to flatten the list of lists im getting back? I could go a slightly longer route and do assertions on the list of lists, or use a lambda before the assert to collect the results but I'd like to keep the assertion as one(e.g. some map asserts then chain some assertions on the contents)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`flatExtracting` is not in the map assertions API (yet), what you can instead is:

```
assertThat(testMap)
        .hasSize(3)
        .extracting("name", "city", "job")
        .flatExtracting(list -> ((List<String>) list))
        .contains("Dave", "Jeff", "Plumber", "Builder", "Dover", "Boston");
```

I ended creating https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1034 to support this use case

Comment: map and flatMap to iterable assertions as aliases of extracting and flatExtracting, are now part of assertj-core-3-18-1 : https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3-18-1-release-notes